# Failing to get hook_form_alter to work

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I'm trying to investigate how to add functionality to a webforms form (want to add a lookup button to populate the form). The issue is that I don't seem to be be able to get hook_form_alter to work as I would expect.

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     $form['test'] = array('#markup' => 'testint 123');
}
```

I know that this would effect ALL forms as is. I'm keeping it *simple* while I test that it's working correctly.

I have a webforms form and would expect the markup to appear on the page, but it's not.

Comment: no problem in ur code..clear the cache pls

Comment: also make sure your module is installed and enabled :-)

Comment: Fresh boot this morning and it's now working. It may have been the cache...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fresh boot this morning and it's now working. It may have been the cache...thanks